# Built in java exception type for permission exceptions

Tags: java, exception

With the view that where it makes sense, we should always use built in exceptions rather than define our own, ie:

- `IllegalArgumentException` - Thrown when a method is passed an invalid parameter, ie null is not allowed
- `IllegalStateException` - Thrown when method is called when it is not allowed to be (ie `setup()` must be called first.

What is the best exception type to throw (if any) when you are throwing an exception due to a user attempting to read or write a resource they do not have permission to operate on. Would you recommend using `SecurityException`  or `AccessControlException`, or does that sound non-sensical.

Answer (score 7):

In my opinion, neither of them. Each exception class serves a purpose, and in this case `SecurityException` is the class of exceptions thrown by the [SecurityManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html) (which is part of the JRE), and `AccessControlException` is a sub type of `SecurityException`.

I think it is not correct (even though the name is pretty) to throw a `SecurityException` when the real cause was that an application-defined permission was not granted (as opposed to permissions enforced by the `SecurityManager`).

You should consider that exceptions are meant to be catch by code that is expected to be able to know how to deal with them. If some function does not know how to "fix" an exception, the exception should be allowed to bubble up the stack. Any code dealing with `SecurityException` will surely not know how to deal with the exceptions raised by your application.

Answer (score 5):

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/AccessControlException.html:

> This exception is thrown by the AccessController to indicate that a requested access (to a critical system resource such as the file system or the network) is denied.
>
> The reason to deny access can vary. For example, the requested permission might be of an incorrect type, contain an invalid value, or request access that is not allowed according to the security policy. Such information should be given whenever possible at the time the exception is thrown.

Sounds pretty close the scenario you're describing. I'd go with `AccessControlException`.

Note there's even a constructor that takes a `Permission` object.

Answer (score 2):

It's not true that you should always use built-in exceptions.  If you are providing an API, then it is more appropriate to throw your own custom-defined exception, such as `MyProjectPermissionException`, if your project is "MyProject".  There are of course many cases where it's still best to throw a built-in `IllegalArgumentException` if the user passes in a blatantly bad argument.

You may also consider placing the actual cause, e.g. `SecurityException`, in your custom-defined exception, if that helps your caller.

```
catch(SecurityException e)
{
    throw new MyProjectPermissionException("Permission denied", e);
}
```

Comment: for unchecked exceptions, type doesn't matter much, since it's not supposed to happen, and people generally don't catch it and recover from it.

Answer (score 0):

I would actually recommend implementing your own, possibly checked, exception for this use case. AFAIK the core API doesn't have anything generalized enough for what you describe.

There is [`AccessDeniedException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/AccessDeniedException.html), but that extends `IOException` and is therefore a checked exception and strictly related to file access.

Answer (score 0):

For checked exceptions, you are better off with a new exception type. Otherwise, if someone catches a `SecurityException`, it'll be unclear what it means.